# HTML audio not playing on Safari but on all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I am pretty new to JavaScript and I have written code to play HTML audio. Audio plays fine across Chrome and Firefox but it's not playing on Safari on Windows. What could be the issue?

Sorry, I cannot post any code here because the nature of work demands so.

Comment: FYI--Safari on Windows is dead -- it's no longer available from Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have `Quick time player` installed on your windows machine.

Comment: urm,nope. I'll install and check!

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Will accept this as the answer as soon SE lets me do it!